# With regards to character design, at what point does inspiration become a derivative work?

Tags: copyright

There is a lot of controversy right now on Palworld being characterized as a knock-off of Pokemon. While the prevailing opinion seems to be that the gameplay and game as a whole cannot possibly an infringement (even though it makes some Pokemon fans, western AAA developers, and game journalists mad), there is some speculation that Pal (the in-game monsters) designs could potentially be infringing on certain designs of Pokemon and could be grounds for legal action. For instance:

- Lamball (Palworld) is a spherical sheep similar to Wooloo (Pokemon), with the main difference being that it has horns instead of braids
- Cremis (Palworld) looks like a white Eevee (Pokemon) with a fluffy mane
- <I don't know the name> (Palworld) looks a bit like a cross between Lucario (Pokemon) and Anubis (Egyptian myth)

Plenty of other Pals (but not all of them) bear resemblance to certain Pokemon, but the above are some of the more "sketchy" examples I can think of from the top of my head. No pals have the same name as any Pokemon and all of them have at least one or two easily-noticeable differences that make them distinct from the Pokemon they bear similarity to (not to mention the numerous gameplay differences). However, some say that The Pokemon Company could potentially make a case that certain Pokemon were used as a base for certain Pal designs, making them derivative works, and therefore sue for copyright infringement specifically over those designs. (obviously if there was a plagiarism-edit job going on here, that would *very clearly* be a derivative work, but there isn't any solid evidence at this time that this is the case)

So the question is:

##### How similar can one character design be to another without being considered a derivative work?

My non-lawyerly instinct is that it depends in part on the creation process, not just how similar the end result is. Does this idea have any basis in law?

If, hypothetically, the character designer sees Wooloo and says to themselves "I like this spherical sheep, so I'd like to make my own for Palworld" and then opens a few tabs of real world sheep and then designs an original spherical sheep creature, then checks back later to Wooloo to ensure their new design cannot be mistaken for a Pokemon, I believe (as a non-lawyer) this would not be classified as a derivative work, but as inspiration. And if this were the process for every single Pal design, there would be no basis for a lawsuit, provided that there are distinct elements in every Pal design. Is this interpretation legally sound?

and some more hypothetical scenarios:

Suppose the character modeler would sometimes have a Pokemon as reference on one screen while he would create the Pal, but intentionally diverged from its design so that it is distinct. Would that make it a derivative work?

Suppose the concept artist started off by drawing a particular Pokemon a few times, then trying a few changes to its design until it looked distinct, would that new monster be considered a derivative work of the Pokemon?

And tangentially, if a YouTuber artist wanted to design an evolved form of an existing Pokemon, would that be considered a derivative work?

If an animator wanted to tell the tale of their triumphant victory in a Nuzlocke and animated several different Pokemon in their own art style as part of the animation, putting aside fair use considerations that might apply, would this be considered derivative?